# How to define model attribute which gets values from multiple tables in django

Tags: django-models

i have a model attribute having the following

```
class ph_no(models.Model):
            phone_no = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
           phone_no_assigned_to = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

actually the value for the field **phone_no_assigned_to** should come from many tables in db like

1. personal_usage
2. bussiness_usage etc..
   Each of the willl have assigned to field

Also this **phone_no_assigned_to** can have mutiple values

Can anyone help me how to define it

Comment: Your question is unclear, but maybe generic relations is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define relationships, i.e. have a model `phone_usage` with usage types and link it to model's `ph_no` field `phone_no_assigned_to`. Or if "usage" is a small list of possible values use `choices`.

Have a look at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#relationships

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#choices